# Show that the set $A=\{g\in L^q(X,\mu): fg\in L(X,\mu) \text{and} \int_X fg d\mu=0\}$ is dense in $L^q(X,\mu)$.

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose $1<p,q<\infty$ are conugate indices, and $f\notin L^p(X,\mu)$. Show that the set $A=\{g\in L^q(X,\mu): fg\in L(X,\mu) \text{and} \int_X fg d\mu=0\}$ is dense in $L^q(X,\mu)$.

My Work:

Define $L_f: L^q\rightarrow$ scalar field where $L_f(g)=\int_X fg d\mu$. Then ker $L_f=A$. So I can use the result of my previous post [Let $X$ be a linear normed space, and $L$ a nontrivial linear functional on $X$. Prove the following are equivalent:](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1208020/let-x-be-a-linear-normed-space-and-l-a-nontrivial-linear-functional-on-x).

So, I tried to show $L_f$ is not bounded. To the contrary assume not. Hence  there is $c>0$ such that given $g$, $|\int_X fg d\mu|\leq c||g||_q$. How can I proceed now?

Comment: What about $\mu$? Is it a finite measure or $\sigma$-finite or ....?

Comment: @saz: This is all of the question.

Comment: Well, usually there are some standing assumptions (in the book or lecture or wherever this exercise is taken from...)